# how to add unnamed c++ class to vector array

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays

I've been trying to rewrite Javascript code into C++ code, but got stuck at this part:

```js
constructor(Counts){
    this.levels=[];
    for(let i=0;i<Counts.length-1;i++){
        this.levels.push(new Level(
            Counts[i],Counts[i+1]
        ));
    }
}
```

It's part of a Javascript class constructor, and if you look closely, there's this part:

```js
this.levels.push(new Level(
   Counts[i],Counts[i+1]
));
```

How do I push an (unnamed) class into an array?

I'm doing this with `std::vector`, because my code base is built on top of a bunch of `vector` arrays.

I tried doing this:

```cpp
std::vector<void*> levels;
levels.push_back(Level l(Counts[i], Counts[i+]));
```

But, of course, that won't work. It gave me a whole page of errors I couldn't understand, and would be too long to paste here.

So, I tried using the `new` method, but that also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: JS and C++ are very different languages.  Instead of trying to convert a JS code block into C++, examine the problem the JS code solves and work out how to solve that using C++.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. There is no "of course", theres only some fragments, and not enough hints on how your code or resulting error looks.

Comment: Looks like the code is trying to have a `std::vector<Level*>`, but I suspect it ought to be `std::vector<Level>`.

Comment: do you actually want to store a class in the vector? or an instance of the class?

Comment: Using `void*` in C++ is a sign things have gone horribly awry. Figure out what you're pushing, and create a vector that takes *exactly* that. If you need to store more than one thing, consider inheritance.

Comment: You are going to find in the near future that `std::vector<void*> levels;` is extremely hard to manage. You do not know that the data is, so either you need to track the type in order to interpret it and ultimately correctly free it or you already need to know the type, and if you do, what's the point of erasing the type?

Comment: If you have a singular type and don't need inheritance, consider `emplace_back` and forget about pointers. Your life will be *significantly* easier.

Comment: Based on the incomplete info provided, I'd say use `std::vector<Level> levels;` then `levels.emplace_back(Counts[i], Counts[i+1]);`. Other than that the question is really unanswerable.

Comment: In `levels.push_back(Level l(Counts[i], Counts[i+]));` if you want an *unnamed* object, you shouldn't use a name for it (`l`).

Comment: C++ is a strongly-typed language and you want effectively no typing. This makes it an extremely hard question to answer. Much more information is required to steer you in a better direction. For all we know this needs to be handled with a template, inheritance or an abomination-untangler like `std::variant`.

Comment: The Javascript shown translates to C++ as: `std::vector<Level*> levels; ... levels.push_back(new Level(Counts[i], Counts[i+1]));` Don't forget a destructor to `delete` each `Level` object: `for(auto level : levels){ delete level; }` You can use `std::unique_ptr` to manage the pointers for you: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Level>> levels; ... levels.push_back(std::make_unique<Level>(Counts[i], Counts[i+1]));`, but best to just eliminate the pointers altogether: `std::vector<Level> levels; ... levels.emplace_back(Counts[i], Counts[i+1]);`

Comment: thanks everyone, I'll make good work of it